# Ищется интересный OpenSource проект

Tags: php, java, opensource, c++, qt

Доброго времени суток!
Ищется интересный, активно развивающийся OpenSource проект для участия в качестве разработчика. Сфера профессиональных интересов и навыки (базовые):

1. C++ (STL, знаком с Qt)
2. Java (знаком с платформой Android,
       очень интересует Java EE, - но в
       этом пока нет знаний)
3. Web-технологии (HTML, CSS, JS,
       jQuery, PHP, ZF, Apache)
4. SQL

Признаюсь, со всеми вышеозначенными технологиями знаком на базовом уровне, как преимущество: материальная сторона вопроса не интересует (хорошо зарабатываю по основному месту работы), имею высокоскоростной доступ в интернет (внерабочее время), готов работать по ночам, выходным и праздникам.

Comment: А на sourceforge смотрели?

Answer (score 6):

code.google.com и конечно sourceforge.net . Там весьма удобный поиск, так что легко выберете проект по возможностям и желаниям.
Смотрите, разбирайтесь, участвуйте и добро пожаловать в Open Source ;)

Answer (score 3):

PokerTH можете посмотреть - он на Qt/c++ написан, развивается активно.

Comment: Кстати, не стоит забывать про github еще.

Answer (score 3):

Можете заглянуть сюда [http://jtalks.org/](http://jtalks.org/display/jtalks/How+to+join+us).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.concrete5.org/ - интересная open source система.

Свяжись со мной. Напиши письмо на feedback@aristarhovnikita.ru.

Расскажу про свой проект.

Comment: Система весьма интересная, используется ZF и jQuery - очень полезно будет в них разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Мы разрабатываем [open source LBS платформу](http://geo2tag.org) смотрие тут http://geo2tag.org/. Если интересно пишите kirill [dot] krinkin [at] gmail [dot] com

Answer (score 0):

Мы сейчас делаем чат на C#.